# how to get value from response in swift which returns [String:AnyObject] Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

in my Api call i getting response in [String : AnyObject] format from this i need to get few elements and store it on Array how to achieve this in Swift4 here my sample response could help how to get values from my response

> My Sample Response :

```
["result": valid: (
    {

    id = 1;
    "name" = "Alen"

},
    {
   id = 12;
    "name" = "Peter"
},
    {
   id = 14;
    "name" = "John"
},
    {
   id = 16;
    "name" = "Ema"
},
    {
   id = 19;
    "name" = "Shane"
},
    {
   id = 211;
    "name" = "Mia"
}
)]
```

From this response i need to get all **"name"** values in array how to acheive this in swift 4

Comment: As "valid" is available in response, does you mean you are getting response like [String: [String:Any]]?

Comment: show your tried code, but your JSON is not valid , is not correct one `result": valid: (`

Comment: The format is not clear. It seems to be a dictionary but the first line is not *valid*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use swiftyJSON for seperate "name" from the response

let jsonData = JSON(data : data)

data - response of your api

then use forloop for adding name data in array

Comment: Between Codable and JSONSerialization, there is little reason to use a 3rd party JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

Hope so, this will help you.

```
struct Details{
let Name    : String
}
```

And where you are getting result from server, use this code and after that  your name values will be in Result Array.

```
 var RecordsArr                                   = [Details]()
let Result = recordJSON.value(forKey: "result") as? [NSDictionary]
for item in Result  {

        let id_records = Details(Name: item[“name”]! as! String)
        RecordsArr.append(id_records)
}
```

Let me tell, if you have any problem.

Comment: Do not use `NSDictionary` in Swift.

Comment: What is the drawback of using NSDictionary in swift, as I'm newbie that's why asking here.

Comment: Swift has a native Dictionary type that is fully type safe.

Comment: Right Man. Thanks

Comment: @rmaddy Can you help me with a small problem.